# Firebase Query not able to query on number field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to query to show a specialistion that belongs to a certain year as follows
{specialisation: something, year: 3}

but the query doesn't seem to work on number fields, the year is saved as 'Number' in firebase. I tried to query on the name of the specialisation and this works fine, it only breaks at the year query.

```
 export const getSpecialisationsForYear = async (year) => {
 const specialisationRef = collection(db, 'specialisaties');

 const q = query(specialisationRef, where('jaar', '==', year));

 const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
 querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });`enter code here`
};
```

Comment: Please post code, not images of code

Comment: posted the code.

Comment: Are you sure the `year` in your code is a number too? Try `where('jaar', '==', Number(year))` and also logging `year` before query to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add Number(year) to my code and now it works, thanks to Dharmaraj I got to the conclusion

Comment: Could you post the snippet here, and indicate where you added the year?